# returning sql query data from Model to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to design an sql data board/dashboard.
I have connected to SQL database using Entity framework 6.

I trying to pull this off by doing a query in Model and then passing the value to Homecontroller

Model

```
 public class LaserRepo
{
    public string CmRlsd3D { get; set; }

    public void CMRlsd3Days()
    {
        WorkflowEntities db = new WorkflowEntities();
        int CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        DateTime firstday = new DateTime(CurrentYear, 1, 25);

        DateTime prevyear = new DateTime(2017, 10, 1);

        DateTime Yday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
        string Dayofweek = Yday.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        int day1 = (int)(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
        if (day1 == 1)
        {
            Yday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4);
        }

        CmRlsd3D   = (from c in db.OrderDetailCheckHistories
                        join d in db.OrderDetails on c.JobNumber equals d.JobNumber
                        where (c.DateTime > firstday && c.DateTime < Yday)
                        where c.FieldName == "Released" || c.FieldName == "Pre Release"
                        where (c.StockCode.Contains("-CA") && !(c.StockCode.Contains("-CAB"))) ||
                        c.StockCode.Contains("-CM") || c.StockCode.Contains("-LP")
                        select new { c.JobNumber }).ToString();                  


    }
```

I would like to pass the total count to my controller/view

```
CmRlsd3D
```

Home Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Laser()
    {
        LaserRepo Lr = new LaserRepo();
        var Cm3D = Lr.CmRlsd3D.Count();
        return View(Lr);
    }
```

Comment: You have not mentioned the issue. Kindly specify it. Are you intending to pass just the count to the view or a 'LaserRepo' view model?

Comment: Yes i am intending to pass the Count to 'LaserRepo' view model

Comment: Since you are passing 'LaserRepo' as your model to the view, you need a  property in the  'LaserRepo' that will hold the count, later you can use this property in the view to access the count.

Comment: Why not just create `int` property and assign it from `Cm3D` value, or pass it to view through `ViewBag`?

Comment: Well i tried that in both cases the value is coming null. The result/value should be 6.

Comment: Is that `var Cm3D = Lr.CmRlsd3D.Count();` returns null value? I think you should change method's return type to count of `JobNumber` instead of using `void`.

Comment: When you create new instance of LaserRepo and pass it to view, it only passes the parameters and their values into view, so if you want to set CmRlsd3D value, you can encapsulate it or you can initiate it in constructor function, when it's initiated, you can pass it to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should know that `Lr.CmRlsd3D.Count();` counts number of certain elements inside the string property, not the number of result sets as intended. Also you have numerous issues there:

a) Multiple `where` clauses is redundant and may not returning desired result. Use `&&` operator for multiple `where` conditions which uses logical `AND`.

b) `select new { c.JobNumber }` uses anonymous type, which I think is unnecessary. `select c.JobNumber` just enough.

c) `ToString()` against LINQ query may returns fully-qualified name of result set type instead of the value. You need to use `FirstOrDefault()`, `SingleOrDefault()` or `foreach` loop iteration to return string value from it.

Therefore, you should use this setup:

1) Use an integer property inside viewmodel class to hold the count.

```
public int CmRlsd3D { get; set; }
```

2) Change method return type to `int` and modify the query using `Count()` to return number of records as provided in example below:

```
public int CMRlsd3Days()
{
    WorkflowEntities db = new WorkflowEntities();
    int CurrentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    DateTime firstday = new DateTime(CurrentYear, 1, 25);

    DateTime prevyear = new DateTime(2017, 10, 1);

    DateTime Yday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
    string Dayofweek = Yday.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    int day1 = (int)(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
    if (day1 == 1)
    {
        Yday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4);
    }

    var count = (from c in db.OrderDetailCheckHistories
                join d in db.OrderDetails on c.JobNumber equals d.JobNumber
                where (c.DateTime > firstday && c.DateTime < Yday)
                && (c.FieldName == "Released" || c.FieldName == "Pre Release")
                && ((c.StockCode.Contains("-CA") && !(c.StockCode.Contains("-CAB"))) ||
                c.StockCode.Contains("-CM") || c.StockCode.Contains("-LP"))
                select c.JobNumber).Count();               

    return count;
}
```

3) Assign the property by the method's result.

```
public ActionResult Laser()
{
    LaserRepo Lr = new LaserRepo();
    Lr.CmRlsd3D = CMRlsd3Days();
    return View(Lr);
}

// alternative using property get definition
public int CmRlsd3D 
{ 
    get
    {
        return CMRlsd3Days();
    }
}
```

4) Inside view page, use `@model LaserRepo` and `@Model.CmRlsd3D` to display it.